# How to change the default filemanager of the Cinnamon desktop?

Tags: arch-linux, desktop-environment, file-manager, cinnamon

I'm running an Arch Linux machine with the cinnamon-git desktop from the Arch User Repository.

The default filemanager is Nautilus, is there any way to change the default filemanager to thunar?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To change the default filemanager you can edit the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

Don't know how to specify thunar but to use nemo over nautilus I do this:

```
thomas@localhost ~> cat .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list 
[Added Associations]
inode/directory=nemo.desktop;
```

Also if you are curious why the wrong filemanager is started if you click on a folder icon check the actual command the starter launches.

After resolving the issues (see comments) you also have to look in the file

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

there you can change the filemanager also:

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
inode/directory=nemo.desktop
```

Comment: This does not work on Fedora 17 "Beefy Miracle". Any idea what causes this?

Comment: @aef Do you have nemo installed, does the file exist?

Comment: Definitely yes.

Comment: @aef How are you starting the filemanager and which desktop are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cinnamon 1.6.7 and I start it using the "Home" directory on the desktop. When I remove the `nautilus` executable from `$PATH`, `nemo` is used. But that's not an update-proof solution.

Comment: I'm not using starters on the desktop. You can try doing a right click on it and check what it actually starts. And you can check your local user configuration directory with `cat ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

Comment: There is no `mimeapps.list` if I don't create one manually. I tried this. This thing on the Desktop is not a normal launcher, it automatically changes when I remove the `nautilus` executable.

Comment: Got some last ideas: `update-alternatives`, `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

Comment: `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` did the trick. I changed the line `inode/directory=nautilus.desktop` to `inode/directory=nemo.desktop` and now Nemo is opened by default.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Gnome section of the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME):

You can trick GNOME into using another file browser by editing the Exec line in /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop. See the correct parameters in the .desktop file of the file manager of your choice, e.g.:

/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop

```
[...]
Exec=thunar %F
OR
Exec=pcmanfm %U
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me. I had to run:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

On Utilities tab, there is a selection for File Manager.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop

find the exec line that tells it what file manager you want to use instead and change it.

so:

```
 Exec=nemo
```

becomes:

```
 Exec=thunar
```

for Thunar to be you default file manager for cinnamon desktop.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what to do with that file? Please keep in mind that answers on this site are expected to be as self-containing and self-explanatory as possible since we want them to benefit as wide an audience as possible, including those with limited U&L admin experience.