# Change the default file manager for everything, not only the toolbar

Tags: centos, file-manager

I am using Centos 7 with gnome3.

I would like to change the default file manager from Nautilus to Thunar.

I followed this : [How to change the default filemanager of the Cinnamon desktop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42316/how-to-change-the-default-filemanager-of-the-cinnamon-desktop) but it's working only for the toolbar at the top. When I double-click a folder in the Desktop, Nautilus is opened.

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 3):

To change the default filemanager you can edit the file

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Don't know how to specify thunar but to use nemo over nautilus I do this:

```
thomas@localhost ~> cat .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list [Added Associations] inode/directory=nemo.desktop;
```

Also if you are curious why the wrong filemanager is started if you click on a folder icon check the actual command the starter launches.

After resolving the issues (see comments) you also have to look in the file :

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

there you can change the filemanager also:

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop inode/directory=nemo.desktop*
```

Comment: It's exactly the link I sent in my post and what I did.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone. Check what you missed because this answer covers everything you need to do.

Comment: `xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory` is only for the current user